# Navigation menu with images and text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a navigation menu that must have images and text inside.
The final result must match the one in attached picture
[image]

That is, the items must have equal space, with no margin for the leftmost and righmost items. Images must have same distance from the top
the html part I wrote:-

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 0.1px; /* IE 9/10 don't like font-size: 0; */
  min-width: 960px;
}
#container div {
  width: 220px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
 
  text-align:center;
}
#container div img {
 background-color:#969;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 
}
#container:after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%; /* Ensures there are at least 2 lines of text, so justification works */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

 <a href=""><div><img src='//placehold.it/100' /><br /><div class='txt'>Home</div></div></a>
  <a href=""><div><img src='//placehold.it/100' /><br /><div class='txt'>Sezione Amministrazione di Condominio</div></div></a>
  <a href=""><div><img src='//placehold.it/100' /><br /><div class='txt'>Log Out</div></div></a>
  <a href=""><div><img src='//placehold.it/100' /><br /><div class='txt'>Chi siamo</div></div></a>
  
</div>​
```

It does not work:- when inner text is wrapped, the images have no longer the same margin distance from top. I also tried using ul and li tags but the result was even worse...
Where is the error?
Thanks in advance.
diego

Comment: I've combined your CSS and HTML snippets to allow them to be run.  May I suggest using a service for the image links in your demo?  http://placehold.it is a good resource for that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion joseph! i am really anxious to see your code run! unfortunately, i was not able to edit my css/html code. in general, images are 100px x 100px maximum. thank  you again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move on from here, I hope this will help you

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#container > a {
  width: calc(260px - 10px);
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  border: solid 1px green;
  float: left;
}

#container > a:last-child {
  width: 180px;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#container > a > img {
 background-color:#969;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#container div.txt {
  border: solid 1px orange;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

#container:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a href="">
    <img src='img/gestione-amministratori-condominio.png' />
    <div class='txt'>Home</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src='img/gestione-amministratori-condominio.png' />
    <div class='txt'>Sezione Amministrazione di Condominio</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src='img/gestione-amministratori-condominio.png' />
    <div class='txt'>Log Out</div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <img src='img/gestione-amministratori-condominio.png' />
    <div class='txt'>Chi siamo</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, caramba! it works perfectly :) that is really i was looking for
thanx again and again and...

Comment: @bitdiego oooh you welcome! I was already about to go and delete the answer as I thought you can not use it... Please upvote and mark as acctepted.